# Check if LVM RAID1 mirrored LV is degraded

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lvm

I have successfully installed Ubuntu to a mirrored LV (two copies in total).

> I am also surprised to find the new mirroring is backed by MD **by default**

It's a Hyper-V virtual machine, and I want to see how LVM reacts when one of the drive is disconnected.

To my surprise, LVM only reports "PV not found". *I've read that LVM would downgrade the mirrored LV to linear in other cases.* (but that's probably if it's a mirrored LVM LV, not MD)

```
root@ceph-1:/home/hsupengjun# lvs
  WARNING: Device for PV 1HzjpO-DJzz-RZHv-5DTe-yI84-tuyf-yB4MQg not found or rejected by a filter.
  LV      VG      Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root-lv root-vg rwi-aor-p- <3.42g                                    100.00
```

I want to know how to get more information about the the raid array, specifically to know if a drive is gone.

#### Notes and Observation

```
# lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.176(2) (2017-11-03)
  Library version: 1.02.145 (2017-11-03)
# uname -ar
Linux ceph-1 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Booting takes another 90s longer as LVM tries to locate the drive.

With `dmesg`, I'm able to see

```
# dmesg | grep mirror
[    1.629767] md/raid1:mdX: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
```

The question is [asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292437/lvm2-builtin-raid-how-to-check-raid-status) without correct answer.

```
# lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices root-vg
  WARNING: Device for PV 1HzjpO-DJzz-RZHv-5DTe-yI84-tuyf-yB4MQg not found or rejected by a filter.
  LV                 Cpy%Sync Devices
  root-lv            100.00   root-lv_rimage_0(0),root-lv_rimage_1(0)
  [root-lv_rimage_0]          /dev/sda2(1)
  [root-lv_rimage_1]          [unknown](1)
  [root-lv_rmeta_0]           /dev/sda2(0)
  [root-lv_rmeta_1]           [unknown](0)
```

When I reattached the drive,

```
# lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices root-vg
  LV                 Cpy%Sync Devices
  root-lv            56.74    root-lv_rimage_0(0),root-lv_rimage_1(0)
  [root-lv_rimage_0]          /dev/sda2(1)
  [root-lv_rimage_1]          /dev/sdb2(1)
  [root-lv_rmeta_0]           /dev/sda2(0)
  [root-lv_rmeta_1]           /dev/sdb2(0)
```

It seems the only way is to check for `[unknown]` in `lvs` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lv_health_status` field of `lvs` is your best bet. Check for it being non-empty. This is documented in [`lvmraid(7)` `DEVICE FAILURE` section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmraid.7.html#Device_Failure)

Here's an example that shows two different LVs with different problems:
 - `home` is `raid10` where a device vanished and appeared again: shows state `refresh needed`
 - `raiddemo` is a 3-leg RAID1, with one device missing: shows state `partial`

```
$ sudo lvs -a -o name,lvattr,lv_health_status,devices --select 'lv_health_status!=""'
  WARNING: Device for PV dR1dqi-eS57-VvWz-XCc2-CUNS-9YcI-1ATu7k not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid dR1dqi-eS57-VvWz-XCc2-CUNS-9YcI-1ATu7k.
  LV              Attr       Health          Devices                                                            
  home            rwi-aor-r- refresh needed  home_rimage_0(0),home_rimage_1(0),home_rimage_2(0),home_rimage_3(0)
  [home_rimage_2] Iwi-aor-r- refresh needed  /dev/sde2(152)                                                     
  [home_rmeta_2]  ewi-aor-r- refresh needed  /dev/sde2(151)
    raiddemo      rwi-a-r-p- partial         raiddemo_rimage_0(0),raiddemo_rimage_1(0),raiddemo_rimage_2(0)
  [raiddemo_rimage_2] Iwi-aor-p- partial         [unknown](1)                                                  
  [raiddemo_rmeta_2]  ewi-aor-p- partial         [unknown](0)
```

You might also be interested in the `lv_active` field, esp. you have a LV that's missing too much to go online (e.g. RAID5 missing two devices).

Lastly, if you don't want to re-implement this yourself, check out
[nagios-plugin-check_raid](https://github.com/glensc/nagios-plugin-check_raid]) which implements checks for DM and many other RAID types.